# Different sequences for subclasses with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am using Fluent NHibernate and table per concrete class for inheritance mappings.

There is an abstract base class and two other subclasses.

My base class has Id column. Created tables are ok. All tables has its own Id column. But sequence is only one for these two tables.

I want to assign different sequence for every subclass.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseMap : ClassMap<Base>
{
    public BaseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public virtual int AmountOfA { get; set; }
}

public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.AmountOfA );
    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public virtual int AmountOfB { get; set; }
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.AmountOfB );
    }
}
```

Is this possible with Fluent NHibernate?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

this is by design.

- `session.Get<Base>(1);` would have undefined behavior because the id is not unique
- consider the case when there is a reference to the base class `Reference(x => x.SomeBase);` with a the value 1 in the database: it would not be possible to know if A(Id: 1) or B(Id: 1) is the object referenced

if Base is only there to reuse the Id property then dont map it as own entity but create a base class

```
public class BaseMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Base
{
    public BaseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    }
}

public class AMap : BaseMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.AmountOfA );
    }
}
```

Comment: My base class is abstract. So there is no Base table in database.

Comment: There is no table for BaseClass in my example either. However you could query the base class and get objects of bth subclasses back

Comment: My all classes are extending I used BaseClass for common fields like version, recordDate vs. With your design my all entities will share same sequence. This is what I don't want in the first place.

Comment: then use my second approach. don't map BaseClass at all but create a BaseClassMap as shown for common properties